# CORS issue with AWS lambda when the payload is too large

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function, deployed with Serverless Framework, that's giving the error below, **only when the Payload is too large**. I'm sending a file through a `POST multipart/form-data` and the CORS is enabled on ApiGateway. But it seems, in case Payload is too large, the lambda doesn't event reach my code, if so AWS returns a response without headers.

**Console**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-lambda-endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Network**

[image]

If I enable [CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) on my browser, then I get a different error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 413
HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes.
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum request payload size for API Gateway is 10MB. If the payload is larger than that API Gateway directly returns the error message you're seeing, without invoking the integration (AWS Lambda in your case).

You can find more information about this and other quotas in the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: Is there any way to define a default header for the API Gateway endpoint responses?